# Use Synergy+ Server on headless computer

Tags: linux, macos, linux-mint, input-device, synergy

I have a headless (kind of) Linux Mint computer with Synergy installed and a MacBook.

Is there any way I can use the headless computer as a Synergy server for the MacBook so I can use the Linux's KB/Mouse with the Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the MacBook is 10.2 or above then both the MacBook and Linux machine meet the system requirements to run Synergy.  The only other requirement you would need is for the two machines to be able to see each other (same local lan, VPN, etc.).  There should be no problem doing this.